# Auditing: How to write SQL user to a table WITHOUT a trigger

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ddl, temporal-tables

I'm trying to find a way to automatically write the value of ORIGINAL_LOGIN() to a column within a table whenever a record is inserted ***or updated***. Note that this needs to be in the SQL layer, so that it can cater for direct SQL updates to the DB as well as updates from the application.

In the past I've used INSTEAD OF triggers to achieve this kind of thing, but I'm using Temporal Tables to maintain the audit history of each of the records and they won't allow the use of triggers, so that option is out.

Whilst researching this and playing with options, I tried using a computed field in the table, which worked fine on the History temporal table, but in the "current" table it always returns the name of the querying user, rather than the user who last wrote the record.

Is there any way I can have the database automatically set the value of a field at the time it is written that doesn't involve triggers?

Comment: You can still use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, only define it on a schema-bound view on the table rather than the table itself. You may need to fiddle with permissions a bit to allow people to insert/update through the view but not the table itself, though I think ownership chaining should take care of it if you grant only `INSERT`/`UPDATE` permission on the view and not the table. (If not, `EXECUTE AS` is required and then you probably want to use `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` rather than `SYSTEM_USER`.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with a default value

```
create table #test (id int, name varchar(50), username varchar(50) default (system_user))

insert into #test (id, name) values (1, 'john'), (2, 'rambo')

select * from #test
```

in my case this returns

```
id name  username
1  john  sa
2  rambo sa
```

Comment: That works fine for inserts, but unfortunately doesn't help with updates. If another user were to update that record, the value of username would remain unchanged.

Comment: yes you are right. For some reason I missed the word `update` in your question